# Javafx menuitem white border

Tags: java, css, javafx-2, menuitem, menubar

i'm trying to change the background color of my menubar and menuitems in Javafx via CSS. I already managed it to change the color of the menubar and the menu but there's a strange problem with the menuitems: After changing the background color, there's always a white border at the top and the bottom. 
This is my CSS Code:

```
.menu-bar {
  -fx-background-color: green;
}

.menu-bar .menu-button:hover, .menu-bar .menu-button:focused, .menu-bar .menu-button:showing {
    -fx-background: -fx-accent;
    -fx-background-color: darkgreen;
    -fx-text-fill: -fx-selection-bar-text;
}

.menu-item {
  -fx-background-color: darkgreen;
}
```

And here's an image of the error: 
[Image](http://www.java-forum.org/attachments/awt-swing-javafx-swt/5733d1381583961-menuitem-hintergrundfarbe-css-voclernrand.jpg) (Sorry, I am not able to post an image, because this is my first post and I've got too few reputation...)

I recognized that the border at the bottom becomes bigger(!) if I add these lines of code:

```
.menu-item {
  -fx-background-color: darkgreen;
  -fx-padding: 0em 0em 0em 0em;
}
```

So apparently it has something to do with the padding, but I don't really know what...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The popup appeared on click of Menu is a `ContextMenu` which has and shows MenuItems. Styling menu items is not enough, the parent/container of them is also should be styled:

```
.context-menu {
    -fx-skin: "com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.ContextMenuSkin";
    -fx-background-color: darkgreen;
    -fx-background-insets: 0, 1, 2;
    -fx-background-radius: 0 6 6 6, 0 5 5 5, 0 4 4 4;
    -fx-padding: 0.333333em 0.083333em 0.666667em 0.083333em; /* 4 1 8 1 */
}
```

P.S. The image you linked cannot be shown due to the authorization of that forum site.

Comment: Excellent answer.